# Update from OS X 10.11 beta release to retail version

Tags: macos

A few days after it was released, I installed the **first beta** of **OS X 10.11** El Capitan on my MacBook Air (Early 2015 model). The El Capitan beta has been running more or less stable and I only had some minor issues that were resolved in later beta releases.

It hasn't occurred to me to check my OS X version for a while. Upon doing so now, OS X still reads "OS X 10.11 Beta", but the Mac App Store doesn't display an available update.

How can I update to the latest retail version of OS X El Capitan?

Comment: I have the same problem :\

Answer (score 1):

I managed to update it now. The new OS X version wouldn't show up in the *Updates* tab of the App Store, but it was still listed on the front page. Just had to download that (which also includes the whole installer, so it's a little bigger) and updated the OS. Now it reads "OS X 10.11.1".

Comment: I just lived with the fact that I was stuck on the beta for a month (or longer?) But some apps kept locking up the whole computer on me and I couldn't figure out why, so now I'm giving updating to 10.11.1 a shot... hopefully it'll fix the random lock ups.